# Can a span tag inherit its input's height parent in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, button

I'm having a problem getting a SPAN (or DIV) inside a button to go to the full height of the button in Firefox (Version 20).

http://jsfiddle.net/spiderplant0/BwwuV/

It works fine in IE10 and Chrome.

Other than just calculating the height for each button and setting it explicitly in px, does anyone know if there is a solution to this?

```
#id1_container {
    display: block; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    box-shadow: none;
    background: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    user-select: none; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

#id1_container > * {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: pink;
}

<button type="button" id="id1_container"><span>hello</span></button>
```

Comment: It looks as though FF needs the position explicitly defined. This is not a final solution, but shows it would take 100% if you position them absolutely. Remove top: 0 and left: 0 to see it still holds 100%. http://jsfiddle.net/BwwuV/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `button` in a `div` in order for the height to take effect.

```
<div>
  <button type="button" id="id1_container">
      <span>hello</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

## [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/BwwuV/13/)

To be completely honest with you, the reasoning behind this is still a bit unclear to me, I'm trying to figure it out myself. All I know is this is the only way to fix your issue without a *hack* like others have suggested.

Comment: With respect, using absolute positioning is not a hack, and this question used a span - so assuming a span was required, the above solutions work. If you want to use a div instead, your solution works.

Comment: @Rockafella IMHO there is no sense in changing the way an element behaves just for this effect when you can simply add a wrapper div which should probably be added regardless.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However in you fiddle I notice that you DO use absolute positioning http://jsfiddle.net/BwwuV/13/ (I also found I didnt need the wrapper DIV).

Comment: @spiderplant0 If you're referring to the absolute positioning on the wrapper element, I'm not sure why that's there but you absolutely do not need it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't reset margin and padding for `span`, it looks like the problem for me. As @Rockafella suggests, using an absolute positioned span would work, hence it appears not ideal for me since your span has 100% width and height. So, try to use an CSS reset code before your markup, like the one offered by Eric Meyer @ http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Not to be rude, but see my answer. You don't need to use absolute positioning.

Comment: I haven't said him to use absolute positioning; I pointed out that absolute positioning would work, although I see it as a hack.

Comment: I don't think that using a div would be that much different of a hack either.

Comment: A div isn't a hack at all. Every element (just about) *should* be wrapped in a div

Comment: Not when they're part of a context (ie. a form context), in my opinion. OP hasn't made that clear.

Comment: What do you mean? Even inside of a form elements are almost always wrapped in `div` tags. PS: I'm not trying to come off as a jerk or anything like that, and I will gladly remove all the comments at the end

Comment: I'm just saying that, if you have a form and that button is part of that form, i see no sense on wrapping every form element inside a div. AFAIK, divs are primarily used as positioning elements, and at the actual question the problem lays about the button and his span - I really believe that a CSS reset would solve the OP's problem