# Firefox BUTTON child element not stretching

Tags: css, firefox, button

I have a problem in Firefox (latest build). I need to place a child element inside a BUTTON element that stretches across the entire button. But I get this: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BJTM6/)**

[image]

Chrome displays it (correctly, I think):

[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
button{height:100px;background:orange;padding:0;border:none;}
button span{display:block;height:100%;background:red}
button::-moz-focus-inner {padding:0;margin:0}
```

And the markup: `<button><span>test</span></button>`

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BJTM6/)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092560/can-a-span-tag-inherit-its-inputs-height-parent-in-firefox

Comment: Possibly, but not entirely. This is a bare-bone example of the same bug, hopefully someone can find a more generic approach to the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning to make the `span` fill the `button`:

```
button {
    position: relative;
    ...
}

button span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    ...
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/j966s/).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in Gecko to me; I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=913759